# Margin for textview

Tags: android

I want to set the `textview` margin, but the following code can't show the `tablerow` and `textview`. What's wrong?

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
table.setStretchAllColumns(true);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    TableRow tablerow = new TableRow(layoutView.getContext());
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        TextView testview = new TextView(layoutView.getContext());
        testview.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        testview.setTextAppearance(layoutView.getContext(), R.style.TextView_SearchContent);
        testview.setText("test");

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
        testview.setLayoutParams(params);
        tablerow.addView(testview);
    }

    table.addView(tablerow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this in code rather than XML?  Also, can you post your XML file?

Comment: Go for xml, stick with the standard way...

Comment: The tablerow and textview no create by xml.it must It automatically generated by the sourcecode.In fact, I wanted to do a report table.